# Python -- lost in a loop and cannot get the proper values

Tags: python

I have been searching for two days and writing Python code for 4.  I need to find a folder that may be nested inside of another folder then return that folder ID and another property. If the folder exists on the top level, I get the proper response, if it exists below that level, I get nothing.  I think what I am asking is, what exactly can I do to stop the function and all parent functions? Once I find the value, I just want it all to stop. I have no aversion to doing it differently (like creating a list of the folder properties) if it's faster.

```
def find_folder(header, folder_list, name):
    x = len(name)
    for folder in folder_list:
        if folder['wstype'] == 'folder':
            if folder['has_subfolders'] == True:
                response = requests.get('https://' + server + '/work/api/v2/customers/1/libraries/active/folders/'
                                        + folder['id'] + '/children', headers=header)
                find_folder(header, response.json()['data'], name)
            if folder['name'][:x] == name:
                #found it, now we need the class on the folder
                resp = requests.get(base_url + '/folders/' + folder['id'] + '/name-value-pairs', headers=header)
                nvps = resp.json()['data']
                docclass = nvps.get('iMan___8','')
                fID = folder['id']
                return fID, docclass

fID, docclass = find_folder(headers, wksp, foldername[1])
```

The output looks like this. The folder I am looking for is Tax Filings and Working Documents is the last folder in the space. The code should stop when it hits Tax Filings and pass back the fID and docclass

```
Tax Documents (P98722)
  Elections and Other Documents (P98722)
  Tax Filings and Estimated Income (P98722)
Working Documents (P98722)
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/mmasteju/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/foobar.py", line 163, in <module> main()
File "C:/Users/mmasteju/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/foobar.py",line 145, in main
fID, docclass = find_folder(headers, wksp, foldername[1])
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I've tried break and pass, I've tried global variables, which worked but was ugly, I don't know what to do next.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your interpretation of the error?

Comment: What's `wksp`, how is it defined? You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee wksp is the parent for the folder and the initial feed for the folder list -- wksp = searchworkspace(headers, {'custom1' : file_info['clientID'], 'custom2' : file_info['matterID']})

Comment: @roganjosh I am guessing that it isn't stopping at the folder I want it to and when it gets to the end, there is no value for either fID or docclass

Comment: But to echo what @roganjosh said, if the final `if`  is never true, the function won't `return` anything (in which case it implicitly does `return None` when it falls off the end).

Comment: That doesn't clarify tanything, now we have to ask what those values mean. Nothing in your example in the comment has a discernible `wstype` so this clearly isn't actually the data your function receives. Voting to close as incomplete / unreproducible.

Comment: I understand that, the issue is that this is returning this way when there is a match, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Then you need to understand your code some more; it's not a problem for us. The function is presumably breaking out and it will implicitly return `None`. Test it; put `return "I'm broken"` at the bottom of the function

Comment: 3 changes: Put the test for name match before the test for `has_subfolders`, so that you can return out as soon as you find a matching name; have the recursive call to find_folder be `return find_folder(...)`; after the for loop add a return in case not found, like `return None, None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find_folder(header, folder_list, name):
    x = len(name)
    
    for folder in folder_list:
        if folder['wstype'] == 'folder' and folder['folder_type'] == 'regular':
            print(folder['name'], folder['folder_type'])
            if folder['has_subfolders'] == True:
                response = requests.get('https://' + server + '/work/api/v2/customers/1/libraries/active/folders/'
                                        + folder['id'] + '/children', headers=header)
                ffid = find_folder(header, response.json()['data'], name)
                if ffid is not None:
                    return ffid
            if folder['name'][:x] == name:
                fID = folder['id']
                if fID is not None:
                    return fID

def getclass(header, folder_id):
    resp = requests.get(base_url + '/folders/' + folder_id + '/name-value-pairs', headers=header)
    nvps = resp.json()['data']
    docclass = nvps.get('iMan___8','')
    return docclass

fID = find_folder(headers, wksp, foldername[1])
if fID is not None:
    docclass = getclass(headers, fID)
```

Thanks @PaulMcG -- you got me going down the right path.
-1,000,000 @roganjosh -1,000,000 @tripleee -- you guys are unhelpful

Answer (score -1):

**initialize variables before the loop. After you assigned them with values break away from the loop.**

```
def find_folder(header, folder_list, name):
 fID, docclass = ''
 # LOOP N OTHER CODE HERE
  if folder['name'][:x] == name:
   fID = fID
   docclass = docclass
   break # put your breake here to break out of the loop

fID, docclass = find_folder(headers, wksp, foldername[1])
```